# Using Python for Erlang-like things: what goes where?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, distributed, agent

I do not yet know much about it, but I've heard that Erlang is somehow special in processing network applications; as I understand it, this comes from some early design decisions that allow it to have thousands of concurrent processes with limited overhead.

I'm essentially a python programmer, and I've enjoyed using 0mq lately for distributed computing [like this](http://taotetek.net/2011/02/02/python-multiprocessing-with-zeromq/), until I came across [this article](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/06/30/zeromq-erlang/) criticizing [this article](http://zeromq.org/blog%3amultithreading-magic).

What is it that Erlang does that is so special for networks/concurrency, and which python library, or set of libraries, attempt to replicate/replace which parts of it?  I'm having trouble understanding /how/ each of these items fit in to the distributed, networked programming picture:

- 0mq wrappers to python
- stackless python
- Twisted Python
- Tornado

(I understand that Celery and RabbitMQ are slightly different beasts in that they are message passing, but they mandate a queue system, which is a particular type of distributed computing.)  How do these "map on" to which functionality, and when should they be used?

I have also reviewed the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519513/erlang-like-concurrency-for-python which is 2 years old.
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423447/which-actor-model-library-framework-for-python-and-erlang-like which assumes the actor model is secret sauce of Erlang---I do not know enough to know that this assumption is the right question.

Comment: I recommend breaking this down into more focused questions. Currently it is so broad that few are likely to tackle it. Try asking a specific question about Erlang, or about Celery/RabbitMQ, or about Tornado, or about the actor model.

Comment: @PaulBissex, You'd be surprised at what people are likely to tackle.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're implying. Hopefully not that a single answer in the 20 months since the question was posted somehow refutes my claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very broad, I'll try to answer few points briefly. Concurrency in any language is not perfect, every language, model, framework, library comes with limitation, they can be perfect for a subset of situations but in general nothing is perfect.

When we compare two languages for concurrency we have to look all aspects. There are number of reasons why Erlang is popular and different then python.

Strong concurrency can help make good, scale-able, robust and fault-tolerant network apps and Erlang have these qualities. I have very little knowledge of python but as far as I know the concurrency in python is not as good as Erlang, see point, as under, to know why I am saying that.

Let me present you few points about Erlang and concurrency in general.

1. Erlang use **OTP library** which is very popular and useful library for network related operations. This is the main reason erlang is considered better for network apps.
2. Green threads are better choice than native threads if implemented carefully and correctly. To the best of my knowledge **Erlang's green processors** (similar but better than green threads) are lightweight and best. Erlang provide its own implementation for process **scheduling** and do not use operating system for this purpose while most of other languages rely on OS.
3. Erlang itroduced the concept of **actors**, which is another abstraction on top of green processes. Erlang can create millions of actors with very small memory foot-print, theses actors communicate **Asynchronously**, which means they donot need locks and hence perform better in network applications.
4. Erlang is roust and **fault-tolerant**. It provided the concept of **supervisors** which keep an eye on actors. If any actor fails to perform its jobs it is its supervisor deal with actors. Supervisors can either terminate that actor and restart it or supervisors can terminate all of its actors and restart.
5. Erlang is a **functional** languages and inherently functional languages are more suitable for concurrency then imperative (or any other paradigm) languages. One of the many reasons is **immutability**, which eliminate fear of race conditions, deadlocks etc.

There are many other features which makes Erlang very suitable for concurrency and hence suitable for network apps. Many other concurrent languages picked up concepts from Erlang which were basically introduced by Erlang.

> actor model is secret sauce of Erlang

That's not true. Scala (via by Akka) and many other languages (or libraries) support actors (similar to Erlang)

Comment: *immutability, which eliminate fear of race conditions,*  Uhmm, I'm an erlang beginner, but "Erlang Programming", has a section describing how race conditions can occur in erlang, provides an example, and mentions that a similar race condition was found in some Erlang library code by someone in 1996, and concludes that race conditions are an ever present danger that you must be on the lookout for.

Comment: Immutability means you will never change state of objects. Objects once created will be read only. Race condition occurs when objects are modified (and then read) in wrong order. So no modification, on race condition. That's how Clojure build its architecture

Comment: read - Avoiding Race Conditions http://www.bigbeeconsultants.co.uk/blog/avoiding-race-conditions

Comment: *Race condition occurs when objects are modified (and then read) in wrong order.*  Based on my reading of the section in 'Programming Erlang", race conditions occur when functions return different results than if the code were to execute sequentially...Well, it's even worse than that: race conditions occur when the return value of a function cannot be predicted with certainty, i.e. its non-deterministic.  Presumably, you could run the function and send it the same arguments 1,000 times and the result might be the same...

Comment: ...but if you reason about what could happen, then it's possible the function could return something different--because two processes are racing to execute the same line of code and you can't determine which process will get there first.

Comment: This is not the proper place to debate and we should not prolong conversation here. I partly agree with you. My argument is immutability may or may not eliminate non-determinism but it helps in eliminating race conditions. Clearly we have different concepts of race condition in our mind and only one of us is right.

Comment: Very well.  Like I said I'm an Erlang beginner, and I'm just relating to you what" Programming Erlang", one of the two main erlang books, says.  The section is titled: "Race Conditions, Deadlocks, and Process Starvation".  You can read the section here: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/erlang-programming/9780596803940/ch04s10.html

Comment: Also, this quote from "Learn You Some Erlang For Great Good!":  *During the previous chapters, we've seen a few examples of common practices on how to write concurrent applications with the languages' built-in facilities: links, monitors, servers, timeouts, trapping exits, etc. There were a few 'gotchas' here and there on the order things need to be done, on how to avoid race conditions or to always remember that a process could die at any time.* -- http://learnyousomeerlang.com/what-is-otp

Comment: I asked this uber broad question back when I knew a lot less and totally forgot about it.  But your excellent discussion here, and the answer above makes me very happy that at some point I had asked this!

Comment: Python has [Pyrlang](https://github.com/Pyrlang/Pyrlang) and [Pykka](https://github.com/jodal/pykka). Give them a try.